# ios creating a custom UISplitViewController, will get my app rejected?

Tags: ios, app-store, uisplitviewcontroller

I created a CUSTOM split view (extends a UISplitviewController) in our application so that it would support a smaller left view or a smaller right view.

[image: smaller left view]

[image: smaller right view]

Guidelines (iOS Human Interface Guidelines)

Avoid creating a right pane that is narrower than the left pane. Although the width of the right pane is up to you, it does not look good to use a width of less than 320 points (which is the width of the left pane).

Avoid displaying a navigation bar in both panes at the same time. Doing this would make it very difficult for users to discern the relationship between the two panes.

In general, indicate the current selection in the left pane in a persistent way. This behavior helps people understand the relationship between the item in the left pane and the contents of the right pane. This is important because the content of the right pane can change, but it should always remain related to the item selected in the left pane.

-------My question is, will my app get rejected in the appstore?. Also take not that I'm displaying a navigation bar on both panes. Because the navigation bar on both panes have a title on it. that's why I need it

UPDATE- I will continue with this and submit my app after a few months, and inform you if it will be rejected or not. thanks for the replies anyway.

Comment: They had mentioned avoid using, not do not use. So i think if it is done in proper way then it will not be rejected.

Comment: It will be my first time to submit an application to the appstore, so I really don't know how strict they are, or if the word avoid means "do not". Anybody who is really sure that what I'm doing won't get my app rejected?

Comment: Lets wait for others opinion...

Comment: Check out Pulse reader, they have a smaller right pane (although it is overlaid)

Comment: thank for the reply @danielbeard but if its, overlaid, then it must be a popover? or is it not?

Comment: @heavyprogrammer not too sure, haven't really used the app for a while. I know that it isn't always present but doesn't look like a popover to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so , They have written avoid . I have never heard that apple rejected some app because of their UI design . there are some restrictions on using their custom UI.  The popular facebook app uses the chat window on the right hand side ... [Check here for snapshots](http://blog.chron.com/techblog/2011/10/at-long-last-facebook-has-an-ipad-app-and-its-slick-if-familiar/)

However , If you need 100 % guarantee then you need to mail apple

Comment: well it looks like a splitview, but it's really one "pane" I mean, look at the navigation bar, one navigation bar for the whole screen. So I'm not really sure if it's a splitview, anyway thank you very much for your response.